# How to make ldap evaluate clear text password vs DES stored password

Tags: hash, active-directory, openldap, des, crypt

I use openldap slapd 2.4.40 and postgresql9.2.23 as back-sql on CentoS 6.9

user and password for LDAP `uid` and `userPassword` are stored in postgresql by DES encoding.

Original clear text is `JacicFk5`

DES encoded/encrypted text is `IfjFxsltK/MPE` which stored in DB.

I can see the user information as the result of ldapseach by stored password.

```
ldapsearch -x  -b "dc=example,dc=com" -D uid="HDZZZ0R0N,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com" -w IfjFxsltK/MPE '(&(uid= HDZZZ0R0N)(objectClass=*))'          
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <dc=example,dc=com> with scope subtree
# filter: (&(uid= HDZZZ0R0N)(objectClass=*))
# requesting: ALL
#

# user01, people, example.com
dn: uid= HDZZZ0R0N,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
cn:: W+aOkl3lia/nlKPnianjg6Hjg7Pjg4bjg4rjg7PjgrnvvIgzNu+8iVNURw==
sn:: W+aOkl3lia/nlKPnianjg6Hjg7Pjg4bjg4rjg7PjgrnvvIgzNu+8iVNURw==
uid: HDZZZ0R0N
userPassword:: SWZqRnhzbHRLL01QRQ==
```

However, I can’t do ldapsearch by original clear text password

```
ldapsearch -x -b "dc=example,dc=com" -D uid="HDZZZ0R0N,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com" -w JacicFk5 '(&(uid= HDZZZ0R0N)(objectClass=*))'
ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)
```

Does anyone tell me how to make ldapsearch to resolve given password by clear text and stored password by DES encoding?

I’d like to know is how to make plaintext `JacicFk5` from ldapseach command-line to hash `IfjFxsltK/MPE` and make it match against `IfjFxsltK/MPE` in DB as `userPassowrd`.

Is there suitable directive for `ldap.conf` or `slapd.conf`?

I've checked followings .

```
echo "SWZqRnhzbHRLL01QRQ==" |perl -MMIME::Base64 -ne 'print decode_base64($_) . "\n"'
```

it returns `IfjFxsltK/MPE`

```
perl -e 'print("userPassword: {crypt}".crypt("JacicFk5","If")."\n");'
```

it returns `userPassword: {crypt}IfjFxsltK/MPE`

One more info.
my ldapseach can solve password text for users stored in AD server via ownclod.

Comment: Well I wanted to convert all passwords stored in LDAP to plaintext. I have always done it the other way around.  Since my answer did not help you I'm deleting it.

Comment: According to configure file for slapd2.4.40  `ppolicy` is not  enabled unless swich was on. `-enable-ppolicy   Password Policy overlay no|yes|mod [no]` Mine is  package for CentOS. I can't change.

Comment: I build same version of slapd by my self with enabling ppolicy.Nothing change.

Comment: I'm ready to customize slapd source now.Does anyone tell me which source file is the best to add DES encryption to make creartext password  match against stored password?

Comment: @tukan , your info was important. you must'nt delete .

Comment: Ok, I have undeleted the post.  You can use crypt (3) `http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/crypt.3.html` (note: he DES algorithm itself has a few quirks which make the use of the
       crypt() interface a very poor choice for anything other than password
       authentication. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want/need to have is a LDAP *simple authentication*.  Please first note that it is **unsecure** to store passwords in plaintext!

First you need to test what auth mechanisms you have supported/allowed.

An example:

```
tukanos@localhost:~# ldapsearch -H ldap:// -x -LLL -s base -b "" supportedSASLMechanisms
dn:
supportedSASLMechanisms: DIGEST-MD5
supportedSASLMechanisms: CRAM-MD5
supportedSASLMechanisms: NTLM
```

Now you want to change the onfiguration via `ldapmodify`.  You prepare a LDIF file (LDIF stands for LDAP Data Interchangable Format)  with configuration.

Prepare your configuration file you can name it `olcSaslSecProps.ldif`:

```
dn: cn=config
replace: olcSaslSecProps
olcSaslSecProps: noanonymous,minssf=0,passcred
```

What the properties mean:

```
noanonymous ... no anonymous connection allowed
minssf=0 ... that defines your effective encryption strength (0 ... no encryption)
passcred ... that would allow password to work as for credentials
```

To quote the [OpenLDAP security considerations](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/security.html)

> Security Strength Factors
>
> The server uses Security Strength Factors (SSF) to indicate the
>   relative strength of protection. A SSF of zero (0) indicates no
>   protections are in place. A SSF of one (1) indicates integrity
>   protection are in place. A SSF greater than one (>1) roughly
>   correlates to the effective encryption key length. For example, DES is
>   56, 3DES is 112, and AES 128, 192, or 256.
>
> A number of administrative controls rely on SSFs associated with TLS
>   and SASL protection in place on an LDAP session.
>
> security controls disallow operations when appropriate protections are
>   not in place. For example:
>
> ```
>     security ssf=1 update_ssf=112
> ```
>
> requires integrity protection for all operations and encryption
>   protection, 3DES equivalent, for update operations (e.g. add, delete,
>   modify, etc.). See slapd.conf(5) for details.

Now to apply the LDIF file:

```
ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:// -f ./olcSaslSecProps.ldif
```

Now to restart the `slapd` daemon:

```
systemctl restart slapd
```

If you check now your configuration you should get `LOGIN` and `PLAIN`:

```
ldapsearch -H ldap:// -x -LLL -s base -b "" supportedSASLMechanisms
dn:
supportedSASLMechanisms: PLAIN
supportedSASLMechanisms: LOGIN
```

Now your search should work with plain test password:

```
ldapsearch -x  -b "dc=example,dc=com" -D uid="HDZZZ0R0N,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com" -w JacicFk5 '(&(uid= HDZZZ0R0N)(objectClass=*))'
```

Comment: Thanks.I tried.However,`ldapsearch -H ldap:// -x -LLL -s base -b "" supportedSASLMechanisms
` dosen't return auth mechanisms before and after applying LDIF. And I can't still login by ORIGINAL password.

Comment: @user1345414 did you change the default port other than `389`?  Could you try `ldapsearch -h localhost -p 389 -x -b "dc=example,dc=com" -s base -LLL supportedSASLMechanisms`?

Comment: I did. And slapd just returns `dn: dc=example,dc=com` Also I tried `ldapsearch -LLL -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -b cn=config dn` and slapd returns `SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s: Authentication method not supported (7)
        additional info: SASL(-4): no mechanism available: security flags do not match required`

Comment: @user1345414 Hmm could you share the config file? `slapcat -F /etc/ldap/slapd.d -b cn=config -l config.ldif` (please replace any sensitive information)

Comment: your command returns `5b990171 str2entry: entry -1 has no dn
slapcat: bad configuration directory!` . But I have cn=config.ldif file `dn: cn=config
objectClass: olcGlobal
cn: config
olcArgsFile: /var/run/openldap/slapd.args
olcPidFile: /var/run/openldap/slapd.pid
structuralObjectClass: olcGlobal
entryUUID: 655d9802-393b-1038-89bd-8f0c8273e5e3
creatorsName: cn=config
createTimestamp: 20180821030943Z
olcPasswordHash: {CRYPT}
olcSizeLimit: 5000
olcPasswordCryptSaltFormat: "_%s"
olcSaslSecProps: noanonymous,minssf=0,passcred`

Comment: `entryCSN: 20180912112827.600157Z#000000#000#000000
modifiersName: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
modifyTimestamp: 20180912112827Z`

Comment: @user1345414 Thanks.  I see you are using `olcPasswordHash: {CRYPT}` (that is the DES you are getting - crypt(3) function) - OS encryption.  I thought you are using SASL (you can remove the configuration I wrote as it is irrelevant for you).  could you try `olcPasswordHash: {PLAIN}`?

Comment: i'll try to do that at the next time. i can't tuch the server now. maybe 12 hours for waitig i need.thanks anyway.

Comment: @user1345414: Ok, I have checked the `man` and it should be CLEARTEXT instead of PLAIN. Also add `olcPPolicyHashCleartext: TRUE` ("This attribute/directive tells the server to save cleartext passwords")

Comment: I had destoried my slapd.Now I recovered it.Result will be next comment.

Comment: `SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
modifying entry "cn=config"
ldap_modify: Undefined attribute type (17)
        additional info: olcPPolicyHashCleartext: attribute type undefined`

Comment: `SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
modifying entry "cn=config"
ldap_modify: Other (e.g., implementation specific) error (80)
        additional info: <olcPasswordHash> no valid hashes found`

Comment: One question is how slapd resolve `JacicFk5` from command line aginst `IfjFxsltK/MPE` in RDB this time. I think your method needs slapd to hash `JacicFk5` into `IfjFxsltK/MPE`.

Comment: @user1345414 Well I wanted to convert all passwords stored in LDAP to plaintext.  I have always done it the other way around.

Comment: thanks revaibal.my issue haven't solved yet,but i want give you my bounty point which already expired. how should i do. i mean operation of this site.

Comment: @user1345414 you accept the answer and below you award the points. (with the check)

Comment: @user1345414 here is how it works: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work

Comment: @user1345414 Thank you :).

Comment: did you get it?

Comment: i still need your help.see you next week.

Comment: @user1345414 yes I got it.  We can have chat to see if I can help you.

Comment: I haven't been able to find the source file which  ldap is comparing input password and stored userPassword so far.I'm ready to have chat  if you don't mind .

Comment: @user1345414 here is the chatroom - https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180263/room-for-tukan-and-user1345414

Comment: Finally i found I must add {CRYPT} on the top of DES text stored in RDB.

Comment: @user1345414 congratulations.  You can create a complete docs and add it as answer I'll upvote it.